# Crear Intervalo de años y extraer valor repetido

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo una tabla parecida a esta:

| nombre | Año |
| --- | --- |
| nombre1 | 1950 |
| nombre2 | 1951 |
| nombre3 | 1952 |
| nombre4 | 1953 |
| nombre5 | 1954 |
| ....... | .... |
| nombre2 | 2019 |
| nombre8 | 2020 |
| nombre4 | 2021 |

Y tengo que extraer el nombre que se repide en todas las dácadas (cada 10 años) desde la fecha mínima hasta la fecha máxima.

Estoy intentando hacer groupby, pero no me acaba de salir el resultado que quiero.

El groupby es el siguiente:

```
datos.groupby('Año').Nombre.nunique().reset_index()
```

El problema es que ese groupby me agrupa los años individualmente y yo quiero extraer los nomobres de las personas que se repiten cada 10 años.

¿Cual podría ser la manera de extraer esta información?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un [example].

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Como te dicen, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de un problema deben presentar un [mre]. Si no, cómo vamos a saber cómo ayudarte? No se puede debugar un problema si no se puede ver qué está haciendo/pasando!

Comment: Tengo una respuesta parcial. Me encantaría mostrártela pero lamentablemente no puedes entrar al [chat], por esa razón vote positivo a tu pregunta, espero que tengas la reputación suficiente pronto y podamos dialogar.